# teste de causalidade de granger cajorls R

Tags: r

Eu gostaria de fazer o teste de causalidade de granger no vec no R dos dados:

```
library(urca)

data(finland)
sjf <- finland
sjf.vecm <- ca.jo(sjf, ecdet = "none", type = "eigen", K = 2,
spec = "longrun", season = 4)
sjf.vecm.rls <- cajorls(sjf.vecm, r = 2)
```

Comment: Não vejo grande relação entre o teste de causalidade de Granger e o código da pergunta (que é só o exemplo da página `help('cajorls')`). O pacote `urca` nem tem uma função para esse teste. Pode explicar melhor o que quer?

Comment: Na verdade, eu gostaria de fazer o teste de causalidade de granger sobre o termo de correção de erro, (no caso ECT), para analisar a causalidade de longo prazo. Também procurei para a função VECM do pacote tsDyn e não localizei nada. Não sei se consegui explicar bem o que eu gostaria

Comment: O pacote `lmtest` tem uma função `grangertest`. Exemplo: `lmtest::grangertest(lrm1.dl1 ~ ect1, data = sjf.vecm.rls$rlm$model)`. Mas há outros pacotes, para os encontrar tente instalar o pacote `sos` e correr `sos::findFn('granger causality test')`.

Comment: Excelente!!! Muito obrigado Rui!!